# PHP login with Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I'm relatively new to php / mysqli i'm having trouble authenticating the user, I'm not exactly sure how to fetch a row and validate the data against it, then redirect user to a new page or display an error(all i know is i need to use _SESSION) . *Basically i'm having trouble with the fetch() routine, what is the right way to code this?*

---

```
  <?php 
    session_start();
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    /* Create a new mysqli object with database connection parameters */
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'draftdb');

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
          echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
          exit();
    }
       /* Create a prepared statement */
    if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT Login_ID, Login_PW,
    FROM login  
    WHERE Login_ID=? AND Login_PW =?"))
     {

          /* Bind parameters
             s - string, b - boolean, i - int, etc */
          $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $username, $password);

          /* Execute it */
          $stmt -> execute();

          /* Bind results */
          $stmt -> bind_result($username, $password);

          /* Fetch the value */

          if($stmt->fetch() == true)

             { 
             $row =$query -> fetch();
             $_SESSION['name'] = $row;
             header("Location:/in.php");
            exit();
             }
        else 
             { 
            echo 'Invalid Login'; 
             } 

          /* Close statement */
          $stmt -> close();
       }

       /* Close connection */
       $mysqli -> close();
    ?>
```

Comment: You really need to salt and hash your passwords. Don't ever store plain-text (or even encrypted...) passwords.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow this order

1. Prepare Query `$stmt->prepare()`
2. Bind Param if you use placeholders `$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);`
3. Execute
4. Bind Results to variables `$stmt->bind_result($username, $password)`
5. The data is now ready to be picked up with `$stmt->fetch()`
6. Close prepared statement `$stmt->close`

I think it isn't clear to you that `$stmt->bind_result()` already sets up variables. In your case you are likely to only fetch 1 row from the table, so `$stmt->fetch()` is enough. If you have multiple rows you need a loop which you use to use the data.

example:

```
$a = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $a = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
}
```

regarding the user and password match:
you now have

```
$_POST['username'];
$_POST['password'];
$username;
$password;
```

so you have have to make an if statement that checks `$_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password`. If this is true, you can set your loggedin flag.

To keep a user logged in just set a $_SESSION variable. You could set `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;`, this gives you the possibility to know the user is already authenticated if this variable is set. If user wants to end his session, just unset the variable (and destroy session).

also one more thing I noticed:

```
if($stmt->fetch() == true) { } // equals: if ($stmt->fetch()) { }
```

Comment: yes my question is what is the syntax for retrieving rows from the table using with fetch() then checking parameters against them?

Comment: @Undermine2k Leon describe the whole process. Just read manual to know what parameters accept this functions and what they are retrieve. You are doing right way.

Answer (score 2):

This has major security issues, but to answer your question:

You can do something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT Login_ID, Login_PW,
  FROM login  
  WHERE Login_ID=?
";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $sql );

// Do your thing...

// Make sure the user is found.
if ( ! $stmt->rowCount() )
    return false;

// Retrieve your results as an associative array.
$user = $stmt->fetch();

// Check the password.
if ( ! $_POST['password'] == $user['Login_PW'] ) )
  return false;

$_SESSION['name'] = $user['Login_ID'];

header("Location:/in.php");

exit();
```

**You might find these useful:**
[Why you Should be using PHP’s PDO for Database Access](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)
[Secure Passwords with Phpass](http://sunnyis.me/blog/secure-passwords/)